# убрать окно уведомлении в открытом браузере через selenium webdriwer

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

При запуске теста в facebook, после логирования, постоянно вылезает окно о "уведомлениях", как их выключить.
Пробовала в основном браузере(которым обычно пользуюсь) и в тестовой режиме, но при каждом запуске по новой появляеться и настройки становятся по умолчанию.
Можно попробовать нажимать каждый раз на ECS. Тогда как правильно вписать эту комманду. Или как это убрать для всех включаемых тестовых браузерах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А они как-то мешают выполнению скрипта? Я без издёвок, просто мне никогда они не мешали. Они же не элемент страницы, а элемент браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На англоязычном СО

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684175/how-to-click-allow-on-show-notifications-popup-using-selenium-webdriver

для Хрома этот вопрос решается добавлением аргумента:

```
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
```

а для Firefox

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908995/how-to-disabling-notification-using-selenium-for-firefox-browser

```
FirefoxOptions.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled",false)
```